# How to connect to a Headless Running VM

Tags: virtualbox

I started a VM using the Headless option. This has always worked fine.  The system comes up, and I'm able to connect to it via rdp with no problems.

At present it's stuck on startup waiting for keyboard input, before the network is fully configured.

The VirtualBox Manager shows the VM as running, but because it was started via the headless CLI, I can't bring it up by double-clicking on it from the GUI interface.

Is there a CLI option to allow me to connect to it and complete the keyboard input it's looking for?

I'm trying to avoid the only other alternative that I'm familiar with:

```
$ VBoxManage controlvm "Windows 10" poweroff soft
```

For a while I was seeing a `black screen` progress of what was happening in the Preview window of the VM VirtualBox Manager GUI.  However at present it's on the screen-blank mode where I can't see the text.  Normally hitting the space bar or an arrow screen would wake put up console so that I can see what it's looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command:

```
VBoxManage controlvm VMName keyboardputscancode <scancodes>
```

where scancodes are those generated by a PC-AT keyboard such as described [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html).

More information on this [VirtualBox forum thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=30173).